Why does dynamic_requests give different values for request.security?
I have a trade plan that is based on a higher timeframe behavior of the stochastics. When I noticed it wasn't marking the trades I expected, I had to start digging in with debugging and logging. I found that the values it calculated were not the same as if I just watched the chart with stochastics on it directly.
My debugging brought me to dynamic_requests = true.  It is a nice feature in version 5, but it seems to cause unreliability in the data.  I use it now to be able to dynamically call request.security on different timeframes based on user input.  However, when I loaded a simpler script to compare, I saw the simple script without any setting for dynamic_requests (which defaults to false) was getting the correct stochastics for the HTF.
Does anyone understand why this is? I don't want to lose this dynamic feature, but it is a show stopper if the data coming out of request.security is unreliable.
This is simple to reproduce with below code. You simply have to toggle the dynamic_requests from false to true and test. You can do it on Replay just add this script to a 1 min chart, but be aware that you have to keep progressing the bar till it changes to the next 9 min bar (create a layout with 1 min on left and 9 min on right to compare). It works fine on the first bar but then drifts. With dynamic_requests=false, it doesnt drift and the values stay true.
//@version=5
indicator("test-data-collector", shorttitle="DataCollector", overlay=true, dynamic_requests = false)
length = 14
kSmooth = 2
dSmooth = 3

fetchLastConfirmedStoch(_tf) =>
    [stoch1, stoch2, stoch3] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, [ta.stoch(close[1], high[1], low[1], length), ta.stoch(close[2], high[2], low[2], length), ta.stoch(close[3], high[3], low[3], length)], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
    [k1, k2, k3] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf,[ta.sma(stoch1, kSmooth), ta.sma(stoch2, kSmooth), ta.sma(stoch3, kSmooth)], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
    [d1, d2, d3] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf,[ta.sma(k1, dSmooth),ta.sma(k2, dSmooth), ta.sma(k3, dSmooth)], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
    textStochastics = "\nK[1]: " + str.tostring(math.round(k1,2)) 
     + "\nK[2]: " + str.tostring(math.round(k2,2)) 
     + "\nK[3]: " + str.tostring(math.round(k3,2)) 
    [k1, d1, k2, d2, k3, d3, textStochastics]


t1 = "3"
t2 = "9"
t3 = "27"
t4 = "81"

// Getting last confirmed stochastic values for different timeframes
[k1_t1, d1_t1, k2_t1, d2_t1, k3_t1, d3_t1, textStochastics_t1] = fetchLastConfirmedStoch(t1)
[k1_t2, d1_t2, k2_t2, d2_t2, k3_t2, d3_t2, textStochastics_t2] = fetchLastConfirmedStoch(t2)
[k1_t3, d1_t3, k2_t3, d2_t3, k3_t3, d3_t3, textStochastics_t3] = fetchLastConfirmedStoch(t3)
[k1_t4, d1_t4, k2_t4, d2_t4, k3_t4, d3_t4, textStochastics_t4] = fetchLastConfirmedStoch(t4)

colorCellHeader = color.blue
colorHeaderText = color.white
tableTextSize = size.small

var table debugTable = table.new(position.bottom_right, 2, 5, border_width=4, border_color=color.gray, frame_color=color.gray, frame_width=4)
table.cell(debugTable, 0, 0, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=colorHeaderText, text="TF")
table.cell(debugTable, 1, 0, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=colorHeaderText, text="Stochastics")

table.cell(debugTable, 0, 1, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=colorHeaderText, text=t1)
table.cell(debugTable, 0, 2, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=colorHeaderText, text=t2)
table.cell(debugTable, 0, 3, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=colorHeaderText, text=t3)
table.cell(debugTable, 0, 4, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=colorHeaderText, text=t4)
table.cell(debugTable, 1, 1, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white, text_size = tableTextSize, text=textStochastics_t1)
table.cell(debugTable, 1, 2, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white, text_size = tableTextSize, text=textStochastics_t2)
table.cell(debugTable, 1, 3, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white, text_size = tableTextSize, text=textStochastics_t3)
table.cell(debugTable, 1, 4, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white, text_size = tableTextSize, text=textStochastics_t4)

